# Changing the default tag in Debug.Log for Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

In order to debug the code for android tags are very helpful to filters the logs on the basis of tags. In Unity 3d when we use

```
Debug.Log
```

By defaults all logs have Unity as tag, is there any way to change this default tag?

Answer (score 0):

Nope there're no way to change the tag(as far as I've seen). As mentioned [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html).

You can however display the log as either error, warning or a normal debug message. Check the [`Debug`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Debug.html) class for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use a logger instead:

```
private static ILogger logger = Debug.unityLogger;
private static string kTag = "MyTag";

private void MyMethod() {    
  logger.logError(kTag, "Error message");
}
```